# How to transfer changes made in SQliteStudio to Flask models (SQlAlchemy)

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, sqlitestudio

Sorry for possibly incorrect Title, but I tried so hard to specify the problem.
So, here is the situation:

1. I'm trying to implicate Miguel Grinberg's Flask Tutorial...
2. I've created the database as it was explained in [tutorial](https://habrahabr.ru/post/346344/) (imported DB into app.py, created models.py, then created some classes, execute migration and everything was fine)
3. But later I've downloaded the Sqlitestudio and made significant changes in the structure of my database with the GUI of Sqlitestudio (cause I am noob and buttons is better for me).

SO, here is the question: is there any way to synchronize current state of my DB (changed with SQlitestudio) with flask migration system? I mean, is it possible to make my app.py 'see' new tables and so on, without mannualy writing the code in models.py ??? 
Sorry for the language, I'm not a native speaker. Thx for Your help.

Comment: I don't think that is possible as Flask-migrate tracks changes to your model : https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/178 and here: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html#auto-generating-migrations